# Ajustar imagen a celda especifica excel

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy intentando ajustar una imagen a una celda pero no logro realizarlo, solo se ajusta en la ubicacion que esta. como puedo hacer para que se ajuste a una celda especifica en su lado superiorizquiero como referencia

```
Sub ajustar()
With Selection
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .ShapeRange.Height = 100
    .ShapeRange.Width = 100
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con ésto

Lo que hace es dejar sin efecto las dimensiones por defecto de la imagen para adaptarla al rango de celdas y luego limita el tamaño por los cuatro lados del rango separándola de cada pared del rango de celdas para que se vea el borde

```
With Selection.ShapeRange
      .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
      .Top = Range("V4").Top + 1
      .Left = Range("V4").Left + 1
      .Width = Range("V4:W6").Width - 1
      .Height = Range("V4:W6").Height - 2
End With
```

EDITADO

Pues suponemos que tienes que insertar imagen1 e imagen2 en Hoja1
Creas una funcion por cada imagen a insertar, en cada función seleccionas la imagen que hay que insertar y olocas el mismo código

```
Sub inserta_foto_imagen1()
    Worksheets("Hoja1").Pictures.Insert("imagen1.jpg").Select
        With Selection.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Top = Range("V4").Top + 1
            .Left = Range("V4").Left + 1
            .Width = Range("V4:W6").Width - 1
            .Height = Range("V4:W6").Height - 2
        End With
End Sub

Sub inserta_foto_imagen2()
   Worksheets("Hoja1").Pictures.Insert("imagen2.jpg").Select
        With Selection.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Top = Range("A37").Top + 1
            .Left = Range("A37").Left + 1
            .Width = Range("A37:F43").Width - 1
            .Height = Range("A37:F43").Height - 2
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Lo estaba buscando en google, muchas gracas por el aporte

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, y si necesito dimensionar 2 imagenes, ejemplo imagen1.jpg e imagen2.jpg como lo puedo hacer

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta y en ella he agregado el código para insertar dos imágenes diferentes

Comment: muy agradecido te tu respuesta, estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo en power point, esto funciona de la misma manera?

Comment: Que va, en PowerPoint va totalmente diferente, te respondo en tu pregunta

Comment: Si no es mucho pedir y la respuesta era lo que buscabas para excel, dale al check para cerrar la pregunta. Gracias